# Stack algorithm is not working pefectly in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I wrote a simple stack code in Java. It is also taking the array length input from user. But this is not working properly. I used two class here.

The user should declare the array length. He/she also push some value in the stack. But every time I run the code it says that the stack is full. But the stack is not full, it should show the numbers.

I don't know where is the problem.

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * Created by Undertaker on 30-Apr-17.
 */
class St {
  int a[];
  int top=-1;
  int n;

  void push(int value){
    if(top<n-1){
      top++;
      a[top]=n;
    } else {
      System.out.println("Stack is full , can't input");
    }
  }

  void pop(){
    if(top>=0){
     top--;
    } else {
     System.out.println("Can not pop , the stack is empty");
    }  
  }

  void print(){
    System.out.println("Current Stack: ");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
      System.out.println(" "+a[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}

public class AlgoPrac {

  public static void main(String []args){
    St s= new St();
    Scanner mz = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the size of you stack");
    int  n= mz.nextInt();
    int a[]= new int[n];

    s.push(5);
    s.push(4);
    s.push(3);
    s.push(2);
    s.push(1);
    s.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: You create an array `a` in `AlgoPrac.main` but you don't assign to `s.a` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int n;` You didn't initialize `n`. So it will remain `0` and at the time of insertion `if(top<n-1)` this conditions fails.

Also you have defined array as a local variable rather your should initialize array of `St` object.

```
int  n= mz.nextInt();
int a[]= new int[n];
```

This two lines creates local variables so you should change it and initialize variables of the object of `St` class.

```
s.n = mz.nextInt();
s.a = new int[s.n];
```

**EDIT :**

Good practice is that you can have a constructor of `St` class and initialize both `n` and `a[]` through it.

```
public St(int n)
{
    this.n = n;
    a = new int[n];
}
```

And then pass `n` in constructor from `main` method.

```
int n = mz.nextInt();
St s = new St(n);
```

You can also use Java's [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class.

Comment: Brother , would u plz tell me where am i supposed to initialize n ? it will helps a lot ..thanks in advance ..:)

Comment: Use constructor to initialize n

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize the fields in your Stack class. You should read about Constructors in Java, since it seems you are new to programming.

The reason the program says the stack is full is that, if not initialized, the default values for type int is 0, so `n` in your stack class is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is below statement

```
int  n= mz.nextInt();
int a[]= new int[n];
```

You are assigning everything to newly created local variables, (i.e creating a local array, with user specified length.)
you should access instance level variable instead.

```
n = mz.nextInt();
a = new int[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

the array a[] is not used, the a of object s is null;
[image]